# Creating and deleting jms queues using jmx in websphere 8.5

Tags: jms, websphere, jmx

I am searching for a way to create and delete jms queues using jmx through a java client.

I know we do get AdminClient for jmx administration. But I am not able to get which mbean 
we can use to create and delete jms queues.

Comment: Note that your question is not entirely clear. By creating and deleting JMS queues, do you mean the javax.jms.Queue objects bound to JNDI or the destinations on the messaging engine/broker itself (or both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConfigService mentioned by Marcin is a low level API that allows to manipulate configuration objects directly. That my be tricky. E.g. if you need to create a SIB destination, then you need to manipulate at least two different types of configuration objects, namely SIB destinations (children of the bus defined at the cell scope) and queue points (children of the messaging engine at the server or cluster scope), and you need to make sure that you link them properly.

Probably it will be easier for you to use the CommandMgr API as described in this [post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=265050). That API is the direct equivalent of the AdminTask object in wsadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You may work with WAS configuration (and create/delete JMS queues in particular) using ConfigService. This article explains how to obtain and use ConfigService:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0307_wang/wang.html

Although it's been written for WAS 5.1, it's still up to date.